# Firefox and IE won't render stylesheet

Tags: html, css

Getting right to the point...I created this small site http://ilmseek.com But I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the CSS file to render in **Firefox** or **IE**.

I apologize for the simple minded question, but as you can tell I'm still very new to this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

But what you guys gave me fixed it in a heartbeat. Can't believe it was something that simple.

I really really appreciate all the help...and not making fun of my lack of skill (though I deserve it for something that simple.)

Comment: Actually its working fine in Chrome, but not in IE or FF, both browsers say: No stylesheet found! :/

Comment: Ah yes, sorry meant IE not Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your css declaration you have

```
type="text/stylesheet"
```

change it to

```
type="text/css"
```

Like somebody else mentioned, you don't need it in HTML5.

Comment: Wow...such a small and simple thing, of course I would look over it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen">
```

but in HTML5 you don't need to use type attribute `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

what the error is that you are using these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script>
```

Change them to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<script>
```

From w3.org: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html. You will learn more about using and rendering and other from here! Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely be spending quite a bit of time on the W3 page.

Comment: Yeah, they will be helping you out !

Answer (score 0):

yes , i checked these template ..if u change the links as i given below, it will function and support IE and firefox.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">    
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">    
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">   
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">   
 <script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are doing it right, you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```